# Game center Authentication not working

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

My Game Center Authentication is not working. When I build and run, it won't show my username.. has signed in. Also, when I try to add my score I get a screen that says "no data availible". Heres my code.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gcAuthPlayer()
        }

@IBAction func GCButton(sender: AnyObject) {



        saveHighScore(GameScene().highScoreNumer)
        showLeaderBoard()
        if GameScene().currentScore > GameScene().highScoreNumer{
            saveHighScore(GameScene().currentScore)
        }


    }
    func showLeaderBoard(){
        let viewController = self.view.window?.rootViewController
        let gcvc = GKGameCenterViewController()

        gcvc.gameCenterDelegate = self

        viewController?.presentViewController(gcvc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    func saveHighScore(number: Int){

        if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated{
            let scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "myleaderboard")

            scoreReporter.value = Int64(number)

            let scoreArray : [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]

            GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: nil)


        }
    }
    func gcAuthPlayer(){
        let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {
            (view, error) in


            if view != nil{
                self.presentViewController(view!, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }else{
                print(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated)

            }

        }



    }

    func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {
        gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code makes no sense

```
         saveHighScore(GameScene().highScoreNumer)
    showLeaderBoard()
    if GameScene().currentScore > GameScene().highScoreNumer{
        saveHighScor
```

You are creating a new instance of GameScene everytime you try to update the score and therefore your score is nil

I would need to see some more code but for now you need to change the score property in your game scene. For example make it a static property so you can get it in other classes.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

       static var currentScore = 0
       static var highscoreNumber = 0
  }
```

Than in your Scenes or ViewController you can get it like so

```
 GameScene.currentScore = 5
 GameScene.highscoreNumber = 5
```

Just remember that you have to reset the score to 0 everytime you restart your gameScene because it a static property.

```
GameScene.currentScore = 0
GameScene.highscoreNumber = 0
```

Than your code to post the score should look like this

```
    saveHighScore(GameScene.highScoreNumer)
    showLeaderBoard()
    if GameScene.currentScore > GameScene.highScoreNumer{
        saveHighScor
```

Your score reporting code should also handle the error and actually do the completion handler. So change it to something like this.

```
  /// Save leaderboard progress
func reportLeaderboardProgress(value: Int, leaderboardID: String) {

    let scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: leaderboardID)
    scoreReporter.value = Int64(value)

    GKScore.reportScores([scoreReporter]) { error in // Trailing Closure syntax
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        print("Reported leaderboard progress \(value) to leaderboardID \(leaderboardID)")
    }
}
```

It is also a good idea to move that code into another class to keep your overall code cleaner and more reusable.
For a nice and simple example check this helper on gitHub.

https://github.com/jackcook/GCHelper

Let me know how it goes.